# Percentage of contribution on community wiki posts

Tags: support, user-interface, design, community-wiki

If I read:

> 63 revs, 12 users 21%
>   Committing to a name

What is it referring to? Number of edits, character count etc...?

Answer (score 1):

- 63 edits in total
- by 12 users
- of whom you made the greatest contribution (21%), roughly measured by the number of lines changed.

For the history and details of this percentage calculation, see [Mixing Oil and Water: Authorship in a Wiki World](http://blog.codinghorror.com/mixing-oil-and-water-authorship-in-a-wiki-world/) by Jeff Atwood. Quote:

> I simply sum the total size of all line contributions (insertions or deletions) from any given author in a revision, with a small bonus multiplier of 2x for the original author. We report the highest percentage of authorship in the final revision.

Comment: Thank you for sharing some of your wisdom, this is consistent with my experience. Also, sorry for the title - It will not occur again.

Comment: Related: Is there any quick way for me to determine the total number of character changes a user has done on a community post?

E.g. In the following link, Makoto has done 94% contribution, and he has done 300k-700k characters changed I would guess.
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/4669/revisions

Comment: Don't know of an easier way than downloading the revision history from  SEDE (PostHistory table) and running some revision-tracking software on it.

Comment: I thought that would be the case. Do you have an example query for extracting the data via Data explorer?

Comment: [Post History Viewer](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.math/query/155370/post-history-viewer?PostId=4669)